# Visual Studio Emulator for Android doesn't connect to VM

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, visual-studio-emulator

I start an x86 Android VM via the `Visual Studio Emulator for Android`.

If I look at the `Hyper-V Manager`, I see that the VM is started. I can actually connect to it via Hyper-V, and it loads and works perfectly.

But the emulator (the thing that looks like a phone) is still stuck at "OS is starting..." It doesn't get farther than that, *even though the VM is fully loaded!*

How do I fix this?

(It's not one of the typical virtual switch problems, as like I say, the VM loads in Hyper-V Manager.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the nuclear option: delete switches, delete VMs, uninstall emulator, uninstall Hyper-V, reboot, reinstall HV, reinstall emulator, ensure firewall rules are not blocking it, reboot. Then run emulator again to recreate switches.

Now I have other problems, but this problem is gone. This is a very brittle product.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suspect this is a configuration issue, possibly inside VS. Android Studio provides a more proper way to create a simulator through a very simple wizard. I suggest you use it to create and launch the emulator, VS will detect it as a device and you will be able to launch it directly from there -no config needed-

A way nicer emulator though is [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com). It runs as an Oracle VirtualBox virtual machine and is way faster than Google's native emulator

Comment: The "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" is faster than both of those options, which is why I'm using it. Also, the problem isn't VS really, as the emulator is a stand-alone program (with a poorly chosen name). Besides, I'm so close to figuring this out, there is no point in switching now. I want to get it to work. Your option is a reasonable alternative though, so thank you.

Comment: Also I can't use Genymotion, as like VirtualBox, it doesn't cooperate properly with Hyper-V (or to be fair, the other way round).